# How to loop over the items in Django?

Tags: python, django

I was stuck to loop my table in template and put only 4 teams in each table.
Here i want to create table groups stage of football. My Table_Team has 8 teams.
So, i want my table in template looping where the table each has 4 teams.

So,how to do it?

Here is my Table

```
class Table_Team(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
    team  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    play = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    win   = models.IntegerField()
    draw  = models.IntegerField()
    loss  = models.IntegerField()
    goalDiff = models.IntegerField()
    points   = models.IntegerField()
```

And here is my Template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <div class="ptable">
                <h1 class="headin">Standings</h1>
                <table>
                <tr class="col">
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Team</th>
                  <th>P</th>
                  <th>W</th>
                  <th>D</th>
                  <th>L</th>
                  <th>GD</th>
                  <th>PTS</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="wpos">
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my function in views.py

```
def group_index(request):
    listGroup = Table_Team.objects.all().values()
    data = {
        "listGroup" : listGroup,
    }
    template = loader.get_template('groups/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(data, request))
```

Sorry for my english. I hope you understand what i mean.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly, i use cycle in these situations, take a look

```
{% for .... %}
    {% cycle '<tr class="wpos">' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' %}
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    {% cycle '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '</tr>' %}
{% endfor %}
```

[Django-Cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)